# how to create a list of favorite files in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, bookmarks, recent-file-list

In GNU Emacs, I want to create a keystroke that will show me a list of my favorite files (not recent files) so that I can easily open them.

Is list-bookmarks the way to do this? Is there a better way to create and save such a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the bookmarks feature gives you what you want, and in fact a little bit more, since you can name bookmarks and bookmark positions in files.

`C-x r m` Add a bookmark for the current file at the current point

`C-x r b` Open a bookmark by name

`C-x r l` List all bookmarks